# Ошибка при установке библиотеки Playsond на Python

Tags: python

У меня возникла ошибка при попытке установки Playsound. Она возникает как при попытках установить его из Python interpreter в Pycharm, так и при введении pip install playsound в консоль. Вот ошибка в консоли:

```
C:\Users\Botinok>pip install playsound
Collecting playsound
  Using cached playsound-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.7 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [28 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lo0x5131\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lo0x5131\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lo0x5131\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lo0x5131\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1262, in getsource
          lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1244, in getsourcelines
          lines, lnum = findsource(object)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Botinok\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\inspect.py", line 1081, in findsource
          raise OSError('could not get source code')
      OSError: could not get source code
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

У меня Windows 10, Python версии 3.11.2 и pip версии 24.0, который я уже пытался обновить.